# Stored Procedure Insert data into XML before insert into table?

Tags: mysql, xml

### EDIT 1:

Learned that if you add

```
for xml auto, elements
```

to the end of the SELECT then you can get the elements like this:

```
<orderline>
  <orderNr>FO123456</orderNr>
  <line>1000</line>
  <company>HI</company>
</orderline>
```

But I still don't know how to insert this into the @XML.

---

I have multiple databases with the same structure and when a certain flag is set I want to execute the following code. The problem is that I am very new to creating XML and can't seem to find any good explanations of how to do this. I hope the code is self-explanatory.

```
DECLARE @XML xml = 
'<message>
    <header>
        <command>
            LOCK_ORDER
        </command>
    </header>
    <data>
        -- I wanna insert the data from the SELECT here --
    </data>
</message>'

SELECT order_num AS orderNr, line_num AS line, orderline.company 
FROM ORDER_LINE orderline 
INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orderline.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orderline.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orderline.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y'

INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT_MESSAGE 
(COM_STATUS, TO_SYSTEM, DATA, TIMESTAMP)
VALUES
(1234, 'TO_SYSTEM', @XML, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this mate:

```
 DECLARE @result xml = null;


SET @result = (SELECT  CONCAT('<message><header><command>LOCK_ORDER</command></header><data>',
    CONCAT((
                SELECT order_num AS orderNr, line_num AS line, orderline.company 
        FROM ORDER_LINE orderline 
        INNER JOIN ITEM_OPTION i on orderline.ITEM_NUM = i.ITEM_NUM and orderline.WAREH_NUM = i.WAREH_NUM and orderline.COMPANY = i.COMPANY 
        WHERE ORDER_NUM = @orderNr and i.MANAGE_STOCK = 'Y' for xml auto,elements
    )
,'</data></message>')
))


SELECT @result;
```

Comment: Works like a mariehøne.

Comment: Wow, been looking all over for this. You are the best, that's a FACT. Thanks, Master!